# How to draw vertical lines of different heights in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

I have an array of integers and for each element of that array , I Want to draw a vertical line on screen of that height.How can I implement this using flutter? Below is the structure that I want but with different heights.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an idea, Try mapping the list,then Use this

```
Row(children:your_intger_list.map((val)=>_widget(height)).toList());


Widget _widget(int height){
   return Container(height:height,width:20,decoration:BoxDecoration(color:Colors.black));
}
```

Comment: Whats the deal with height/200?

Comment: nevermind, thats a mistake, just enter the height there, I will edit that,and set the width of the container according to your need.